# VersionResolutionException: Failed to resolve version RELEASE

Tags: maven, repository

> Suddenly Maven is unable to resolve dependency with version
>   **RELEASE**.

For example:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
            <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

On maven install I'm getting following error:-

```
 Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.api-ads:ads-lib:jar:RELEASE
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.api-ads:ads-lib:jar:RELEASE
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.VersionResolutionException: Failed to resolve version for com.google.api-ads:ads-lib:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata com.google.api-ads:ads-lib/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ashwani.kumar\.m2\repository)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:231)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata com.google.api-ads:ads-lib/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ashwani.kumar\.m2\repository)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:237)
    ... 34 more
```

Also I'm not able to see any RELEASE versions for the dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-ads/ads-lib

On further exploration I have found the article https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version

According to it:-

> **Deprecated Syntax**
>
> Maven2 also provided two special metaversion values to achieve the
>   result: LATEST and RELEASE.
>
> However, this legacy upgrade method was causing unpredictability where
>   CI needed reproducibility. Hence, they’ve been deprecated and
>   completely removed in Maven3:
>
> For the sake of reproducible builds, Maven 3.x no longer supports
>   usage of these metaversions in the POM
>
> Is there any solution other than **Versions Maven Plugin** ?

Comment: you have to set a version like `2.4.5` ...which is a release version...

Comment: "Is there any solution other than Versions Maven Plugin?": Solution to which problem? The Versions Maven plugin allows you to update version numbers, you can also do it manually. Nowadays you only use explicit versions, not labels like REÄLEASE or LATEST.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Try to update the local metadata passing the `-U` arg to the maven command line:

```
 mvn -U install
```

---

In my case maven thought that the local metadata is up-to-date and thus skipped the download of the remote metadata.

I saw it in the debug log:

```
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.dbunit:dbunit/maven-metadata.xml locally installed metadata up-to-date.
```

But sadly this was not true. The local metadata was this:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <versions>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20220811072909</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

while the remote metadata was this

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>2.7.3</latest>
        <release>2.7.3</release>
        <versions>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20220213055459</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

as you can see the remote meta data contains a lot more versions and the `<release>` and `<latest>` tags. The local did not contain it.

I guess this was the problem why maven could not detect the `RELEASE` version anymore. But the `LATEST` version strangely works even there is no `<latest>` tag in the meta data. It seems that maven looks at the `release` tag to determine the `RELEASE` version, but for the `LATEST` version it searches the `<versions>` list.